# Spring SimpleThreadScope not properly autowired on @Components

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have a Spring Boot application and I need to have beans that are thread-bound. I want the solution where I need to use Spring's SimpleThreadScope. I tried autowiring it to @Components but based on the logs I print, it looks like that Spring does not create a new bean for each spawned thread. How do I properly autowire/ configure the bean?

Here is my Controller

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
  @Autowired
  private DummyClass dummyClass;

  @Autowired
  private DummyService1 svc;

  @PostMapping  
  public Result myPostMethod (@RequestBody Request request) {    
    LOGGER.info("myPostMethod " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + Integer.toHexString(this.dummyClass.hashCode()));
    this.svc.doSomething();

    return new Result();
  }
}
```

My sample services

```
@Service
public class DummyService1 {

  @Autowired
  private DummyClass dummyClass;

  @Autowired
  private DummyService2 service;

  public void doSomething () {
    LOGGER.info("doSomething " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + Integer.toHexString(this.dummyClass.hashCode()));

    this.service.doSomething2();
  }
}

@Service
public class DummyService2 {  

  @Autowired
  private DummyClass dummyClass;

  public void doSomething2 () {
    LOGGER.info("doSomething2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + Integer.toHexString(this.dummyClass.hashCode()));
  }
}
```

My configuration

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Bean
  @Scope(value = "thread", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)  
  public DummyClass dummyClass () {
    DummyClass ctx = new DummyClass();
    return ctx;
  }

  @Bean
  public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor beanFactoryPostProcessor () {
    return new CustomScopeRegisteringBeanFactoryPostProcessor();
  }
}

public class CustomScopeRegisteringBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    beanFactory.registerScope("thread", new SimpleThreadScope());
  }
}
```

Actual output after 2 executions

```
myPostMethod http-nio-8080-exec-4 81823b32
doSomething http-nio-8080-exec-4 81823b32
doSomething2 http-nio-8080-exec-4 81823b32

myPostMethod http-nio-8080-exec-8 81823b32
doSomething http-nio-8080-exec-8 81823b32
doSomething2 http-nio-8080-exec-8 81823b32
```

Expected output after 2 executions

```
myPostMethod http-nio-8080-exec-4 81823b32
doSomething http-nio-8080-exec-4 81823b32
doSomething2 http-nio-8080-exec-4 81823b32

myPostMethod http-nio-8080-exec-8 9a5170d
doSomething http-nio-8080-exec-8 9a5170d
doSomething2 http-nio-8080-exec-8 9a5170d
```

I noticed that if I execute a method (set or get) in the DummyClass, a new instance will be created per thread. My problem is, that newly created object is not being injected in the components (DummyService1 and DummyService2)

Comment: `myPostMethod` has been executed twice in the same thread, why are you expecting it to be executed in a different thread?

Comment: Forgot to say that the myPostMethod was called via Postman. So the 2 executions are 2 different requests

Comment: but these requests were directed to the same thread, shouldn't they share the same `DummyClass` instance?

Comment: My goal here is to have a different DummyClass per thread

Comment: @racumin according to the logs `myPostMethod` was executed twice in the same thread `http-nio-8080-exec-4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST` which is part of Web Aware Scopes that always provide different bean for every request

```
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

Comment: OP never mentioned they want "instance per request"  instead of "instance per thread"

Comment: i believe every request from postman will be accessed by different thread

Comment: It may, or it may not. There is a thread pool, and you basically don't know which thread will handle your next request.

Comment: Correct, but at a time one thread can't process two requests, i believe OP is looking for 'RequestScope' or 'PrototypeScope', let him try we will wait for his response

Comment: Request scope is working fine. But I will have some async calls inside my service so I can't use request scope. That is why I chose the thread-bound approach.

Comment: I believe this should also work for Async, because this requestscope provide bean on every request. Suppose your container thread is calling 10 times Async method then 10 threads will work in parallel with 10 different objects. If you don't want this way, then make your container thread to call this requestScope object, then pass this object for every Async call